# How can I get CloudFormation stack by an output name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I deploy a CloudFormation stack to AWS I got this error message:

> An error occurred: apiGatewayEndpoint - ERROR Parameter Name api-endpoint with a
> different configuration already exists

it can be caused by I export a name which has already been exported by other stacks. Is there a way for me to find the stack name by searching for an exported name?

Comment: Search where? In AWS console?

Comment: I don't mind either aws console or command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFormation console has dedicated section for exports where you can search by export name:

[image]